# C++ How to store million objects into array with no segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

How  can I store million objects into array without error?
I'm playing with a 3dEngine in C++ , all works nice and fast but  i can't add more than 50K Objects . Object contains 3 vector and  colors and some useful method . Some Help ?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Myc{
    public:
    double x,y,z;
    Myc(double _x=0 ,double _y=0,double _z=0){
        x=_x;y=_y;z=_z;
    }
};

int main(){
    int i; 
    int N=151000;
    Myc pts[N];
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        pts[i] = Myc(1,1,1);
    }
    
    cout << pts[999].x <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
...Program finished with exit code 0
```

But using `int N=1151000;`

the output is :

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How  can I store million objects into array without error? Thanks .

Comment: Classic example of stack overflow. Default stack size is limited (for example 1 MB on windows). Use `Myc * pts = new Myc[N];` or `std::vector<Myc> pts; pts.resize(N);`

Comment: Array data is stored on the stack, which does not have enough space for a million elements. You could use `std::vector` or perhaps even a dynamic array.

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate the memory on the heap (dynamically allocate it). Currently you are getting stack overflow.

Another way is to do:
`ulimit -s unlimited` on any Linux system to increase the stack size but I advise you to go with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Myc{
    public:
    double x,y,z;
    Myc(double _x=0 ,double _y=0,double _z=0){
        x=_x;y=_y;z=_z;
    }
};

int main(){
    int i; 
    int N=151000;

    std::vector<Myc> pts(N); // stores its data in the free store (heap)

    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        pts[i] = Myc(1,1,1);
    }
    
    cout << pts[999].x <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) stored its internal array on the *free store* (heap) which has a lot more memory that the function stack, which is where local variables like your array are kept.

Answer (score 0):

use a `std::vector` and insert calling the `pts.emplace_back` method

```
int main(){
    int i; 
    int N = 9999999;
    std::vector<Myc> pts;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        pts.emplace_back(Myc(1, 1, 1));
    }
    
    cout << pts[999].x <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When there are `9999999` objects it's going to be signifcantly better to reserve the space needed, `pts.reserve(N);`.